# How to boot old WORKING hard drive again after made slave?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I have an old *working* SATA hard drive - zero problems with it. I removed it, installed a new SSD drive and restored the SSD back to factory specs. All is good so far. I put the old drive in a USB caddy so I could copy some larger files from it to my new SSD drive. Again so far so good. Well, now I need to get my Internet Explorer passwords from the old drive so I removed the SSD drive, pulled the old drive from the USB caddy and put it where it came from from DELL.  Now, the drive will not boot.  As a USB Drive, I can see the files there and various tools do not report any physical problems with the drive.  I've spent a lot of time to simply get a couple of passwords. Grrrr

System:  DELL XPS 1702
Original Hard Drive: 500gb x 2 SATA
OS: Windows 7 I do have a recovery disk

I did attempt to use the Windows recovery disk but that didn't seem to do anything significant.  I haven't tried anything other than that because I didn't want to make anything worse. As it is now, I can at least get to docs.

Are there any other options I can try to get this to boot up again?

Comment: The title makes little sense.  SATA drivers can't be `Master/Slave` thats something PATA supported

Comment: @dlackey, in response to your comment on SO, http://stackexchange.com/sites is where you can see a listing of all of the sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and boot from a Windows 7 [system repair disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc), and "repair" the installation.

If the repair disk can't see your drive, then you may want to check you BIOS to see what mode your HDD controller is in.

If it's in AHCI or RAID mode, then you'll need to provide a HDD controller driver for the Windows start-up/repair disks to be able to see the drive.

According to Dell's site, it looks like that system used an Intel Chipset, and Dell provides the [Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/xps-l702x?driverId=YM5WC&osCode=W764&fileId=3277997645&languageCode=en&categoryId=SA).  Unzip this to a USB key or alike, and then when given the chance by the install/repair disk, "Load the driver" and point it to the unzipped driver.

Alternatively (and probably best for you exact scenario), just set the BIOS back to ATA for now. :)

Comment: Tried that - no go. :(  When the system repait disk started up, there were two radio options, 1) to repair and 2) to restore.  The windows installation was not visible by the system repair disk.  the repair disk was from a different computer.  Are the repair disk system specific?

Comment: @dlackey - No they are not system specific.

Comment: @dlackey Nope, it should work regardless of where you made it.  Are you sure you haven't changed the mode the HDD controller uses (in your BIOS)?  You may want to check that anyway, because if it's in AHCI mode, RAID mode or something, then you need to provide a HDD controller driver for the Windows startup/repair disks to be able to see the drive.

Comment: Actually, I literally just watched a YouTube video talking about optimizing the pc for an SSD drive and it mentioned AHCI.  My bios only has two options, ATA and AHCI so I think you might be on to something.  Can you expand on how to do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Updated my answer to cover the controller modes. :)

Comment: WOW!  I'll try this during my lunch break today.  Out of curiosity, my laptop supports booting from a usb drive.  Is it possible to pop in my repair disk and boot from the USB drive so that I don't have to expose the insides of my laptop unnecessarily or could the bios be confused between the two controllers?  I'd like to do the easiest way possible but not at the risk of making the old c drive unbootable.

Comment: Booting Windows from an external USB drive is NOT an easy task (it's barely possible) so I wouldn't go that route. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to boot up under the other drive, simply access the registry as explained here: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-offline-registry-edit.html

Then export your passwords stored here:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\IntelliForms\SPW`

And finally, import them on your own system.

Comment: I do not think it will be that straightforward.  There is an algorithm involved when saving the passwords.  I don't understand it all but this is the concept - the existing web url is part of the algorithm key needed to unlock the password.